# ColdFusion - Capture Login Date / Time and Logout Date / Time

Tags: session, coldfusion, session-timeout

I want to know if there is a way to capture a users id when their session times out. I can capture if they click a logout button. I just want to be able to capture if their session times out.

Added this below

```
<cffunction name="onSessionEnd" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfquery name="logout" datasource="#application.datasource#">
        update user 
        set logout_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        where profile_id = #session.user_id#
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

So I did the above It is not recording the logout date when the session times out.

Comment: You can capture that sort of information in [OnSessionStart](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/onsessionstart.html) and [OnSessionEnd](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/onsessionend.html).

Comment: Once the session is dead and you get to OnSessionEnd where would I get the users ID to be able to log that they are now logged out? what scope would still be available?

Comment: As the session times out, onSessionEnd will be triggered. Any session variable will exist until that function finishes executing.

Comment: So in that function I would need to run a query to store to the database.

Comment: Or log it out to a file and read it in later.  Lots of ways to do it, but that would be the ideal way.

Comment: *what scope would still be available* Note, if you read the OnSessionEnd docs, it explains the session variables for the terminated session will be available in `arguments.SessionScope` (*not* the standard `session` scope).

Comment: So if the database name is in the request scope and I am in SessionEnd how will I get that? It is  different on different servers, Development, Test, Stage, Production?

Comment: @NathanStanford - The Request scope is not accessible inside OnSessionEnd. Whatever values are needed must be stored in an accessible scope like `application` or `session`. Application is usually the appropriate choice for dsn settings, as they are typically the same for all users and tend not to change during the life of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Adding this comment as an answer for better formatting

Leigh deserves the credit. If you add your answer I will remove this one in favor of yours.*

Given the example that you just added to your answer, you are doing it wrong. As Leigh pointed out in his comments you need to reference the session scope differently inside the `OnSessionEnd` method.

You are also missing the arguments for the `OnSessionEnd` method.

You will probably also want to make sure the variables are defined before trying to use them.

You should also use `<cfqueryparam>` within your queries.

Put it all together and it should look something like this:

```
<cffunction name="OnSessionEnd" access="public" returntype="void" output="false">
    <cfargument name="SessionScope" type="struct" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="ApplicationScope" type="struct" required="false" default="#StructNew()#" />

    <cfif StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.ApplicationScope,"datasource") AND StructKeyExists(ARGUMENTS.SessionScope,"user_id")>

        <cfquery name="local.logout" datasource="#ARGUMENTS.ApplicationScope.datasource#">
            update user 
            set logout_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            where profile_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ARGUMENTS.SessionScope.user_id#" />
        </cfquery>

    <cfelse>

        <!--- variables are not defined, do something else here? --->

    </cfif>

    <cfreturn />
</cffunction>
```

Also, the request scope is not available within this method because it is not called by a request.

Comment: Thanks, but that covers it pretty well :-) Only thing I would add is the two structures representing the app and session scopes should always exist, so you could probably go with structKeyExists instead of IsDefined (and drop the query "name")

Comment: Thanks @Leigh. I changed the answer to use `StructKeyExists()` instead of `IsDefined()` as you suggested. Isn't the query `name` attribute required though?

Comment: (Edit) Technically I think it is optional.  For `select` statements obviously it is needed to capture the result, but it does not really do anything for `delete/insert/update` as they do not return a resultset. Does not hurt anything to keep "name", but if you did I would `local` scope it.

Comment: Interesting. I always thought it was required.

Comment: I did too, and still use it out of habit, but ... back in CF8 I remember doing a lot of testing involving the new "result" attribute and generated id's and was surprised to discover it is not actually mandatory. Maybe it was at some point, and they just never updated the docs?

Answer (score 0):

So had to change the application variable to a session variable only one that worked for me.

```
<cffunction name="onSessionEnd" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfquery name="logout" datasource="#session.datasource#">
        update user 
        set logout_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        where profile_id = #session.user_id#
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: I jumped to quickly it worked if I clicked the logout button but the above still did not work.  what is wrong now?

Comment: Since there are several issues with the above (which Miguel-F has since addressed) you may want to delete this answer so it is not confusing to the next guy.